# LINQ-to-XML Selecting tags inside the root

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I'm new to LINQ-to-XML and I'm trying to learn the query structure. I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <list>
  <item>
   <due>07 May 2012</due>
   <name>Name</name>
   <desc>Description</desc>
   <colour>White</colour>
  </item>
  <item>
   <due>12 May 2012</due>
   <name>Name2</name>
   <desc>Desc2</desc>
   <colour>White</colour>
  </item>
</list>
```

And I'm trying to delete `<item>` elements with a query:

`Dim DeleteItems = From e In Root.Elements("list") Where e.Element("name").Value = Text`

However it isn't working. I think it's trying to select tags called `<item>` in the file's root, however it needs to be selecting `<item>` tags in the `<list>` element - which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `Root` is you XDocument object name.

Change `Elements` do `Descendants` and it should work then.

```
Dim DeleteItems = From e In Root.Descendants("item") Where e.Element("name").Value = Text
```

Comment: Yea - I never saw that you answered, however, thankfully I figured this out on my own this time. I referred to the selected item's first index (name) to make sure it wasn't just using anything. Thanks!